# Converting list of 2D Panda's DataFrame to 3D DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a Pandas DataFrame that holds label values to a 2D DataFrame. This is what I have done so far:

I am reading csv files using `pd.read_csv` and appending them to list, for the purpose of this question let's consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_sample = []
labels = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
samples = np.random.randn(6, 5, 4)
for contents in range(samples.shape[0]):
    raw_sample.append(pd.DataFrame(samples[contents]))
```

Then, I added `raw_sample` to `df=d.DataFrame(raw_sample)`. Then I added the labels to `df` by doing the following:

```
df = df.set_index([df.index, labels])
df.index = df.index.set_names('index', level=0)
df.index = df.index.set_names('labels', level=1)
```

I tried printing this and I got

```
                                                              0
index labels                                                   
0     1                 0         1         2         3
0  0...
1     1                 0         1         2         3
0  0...
2     1                 0         1         2         3
0  1...
3     2                 0         1         2         3
0 -0...
4     2                 0         1         2         3
0  0...
5     2                 0         1         2         3
0 -0...
```

I have also tried printing `df[0]`, I still got the same thing.

I wanted to know if it is in the form of

```
index  labels         0
  0      1      1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                3 5 6 7 9 5 4
                3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  1      1      4 3 2 4 5 6 7
                3 5 6 7 4 5 6 
                2 3 4 3 4 5 3
...
```

I know that a DataFrame cannot take 2D array, the other thing was to use `pd.Panel`, for this I converted all the contents of `raw_sample` to numpy array and then converted `raw_sample` itself to numpy array and did the following:

```
p1 = pd.Panel(samples, items=map(str, labels))
```

but when I print this, I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1 to 2
Major_axis axis: 0 to 4
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 3
```

Looking at the `Items`, it looks like all the common values are grouped together.

I am not sure what to do at this point. Help!!

**Update**

Inputs:

```
labels = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
samples = [5x4 pd.DataFrame, 5x4 pd.DataFrame, 5x4 pd.DataFrame, 5x4 pd.DataFrame, 5x4 pd.DataFrame, 5x4 pd.DataFrame]
```

Desired Output:

```
index  labels      samples
  0      1      1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                3 5 6 7 9 5 4
                3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  1      1      4 3 2 4 5 6 7
                3 5 6 7 4 5 6 
                2 3 4 3 4 5 3
...
```

Comment: Not sure what you need exactly. Can you please just give us your input and the desired output?

Comment: @Allen Updated. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but seems you need unique `labels`, so change `labels = [1,1,1,2,2,2]` to `labels = list('abcdef')` and then is possible select by `print (p1['a'])`

Comment: @jezrael But the labels cannot be unique.

Comment: @akshay - yes, it is possible. But if test `print (p1)` vs `print (p1['1'])` then get panels in both ways, only second is filtered - `Dimensions: 6 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)` vs `Dimensions: 3 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If select with not unique items, get another `Panel`:

```
np.random.seed(10)
labels = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
samples = np.random.randn(6, 5, 4)
p1 = pd.Panel(samples, items=map(str, labels))
print (p1)
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1 to 2
Major_axis axis: 0 to 4
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 3

print (p1['1'])
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1 to 1
Major_axis axis: 0 to 4
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 3
```

```
print (p1.to_frame())
                    1         1         1         2         2         2
major minor                                                            
0     0      1.331587  1.331587  1.331587 -0.232182 -0.232182 -0.232182
      1      0.715279  0.715279  0.715279 -0.501729 -0.501729 -0.501729
      2     -1.545400 -1.545400 -1.545400  1.128785  1.128785  1.128785
      3     -0.008384 -0.008384 -0.008384 -0.697810 -0.697810 -0.697810
1     0      0.621336  0.621336  0.621336 -0.081122 -0.081122 -0.081122
      1     -0.720086 -0.720086 -0.720086 -0.529296 -0.529296 -0.529296
      2      0.265512  0.265512  0.265512  1.046183  1.046183  1.046183
      3      0.108549  0.108549  0.108549 -1.418556 -1.418556 -1.418556
2     0      0.004291  0.004291  0.004291 -0.362499 -0.362499 -0.362499
      1     -0.174600 -0.174600 -0.174600 -0.121906 -0.121906 -0.121906
      2      0.433026  0.433026  0.433026  0.319356  0.319356  0.319356
      3      1.203037  1.203037  1.203037  0.460903  0.460903  0.460903
3     0     -0.965066 -0.965066 -0.965066 -0.215790 -0.215790 -0.215790
      1      1.028274  1.028274  1.028274  0.989072  0.989072  0.989072
      2      0.228630  0.228630  0.228630  0.314754  0.314754  0.314754
      3      0.445138  0.445138  0.445138  2.467651  2.467651  2.467651
4     0     -1.136602 -1.136602 -1.136602 -1.508321 -1.508321 -1.508321
      1      0.135137  0.135137  0.135137  0.620601  0.620601  0.620601
      2      1.484537  1.484537  1.484537 -1.045133 -1.045133 -1.045133
      3     -1.079805 -1.079805 -1.079805 -0.798009 -0.798009 -0.798009
```

But if have unique one, get `DataFrame`:

```
np.random.seed(10)
labels = list('abcdef')
samples = np.random.randn(6, 5, 4)
p1 = pd.Panel(samples, items=labels)
print (p1)
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to f
Major_axis axis: 0 to 4
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 3

print (p1['a'])
          0         1         2         3
0  1.331587  0.715279 -1.545400 -0.008384
1  0.621336 -0.720086  0.265512  0.108549
2  0.004291 -0.174600  0.433026  1.203037
3 -0.965066  1.028274  0.228630  0.445138
4 -1.136602  0.135137  1.484537 -1.079805
```

```
print (p1.to_frame())
                    a         b         c         d         e         f
major minor                                                            
0     0      1.331587 -1.977728  0.660232 -0.232182  1.985085  0.117476
      1      0.715279 -1.743372 -0.350872 -0.501729  1.744814 -1.907457
      2     -1.545400  0.266070 -0.939433  1.128785 -1.856185 -0.922909
      3     -0.008384  2.384967 -0.489337 -0.697810 -0.222774  0.469751
1     0      0.621336  1.123691 -0.804591 -0.081122 -0.065848 -0.144367
      1     -0.720086  1.672622 -0.212698 -0.529296 -2.131712 -0.400138
      2      0.265512  0.099149 -0.339140  1.046183 -0.048831 -0.295984
      3      0.108549  1.397996  0.312170 -1.418556  0.393341  0.848209
2     0      0.004291 -0.271248  0.565153 -0.362499  0.217265  0.706830
      1     -0.174600  0.613204 -0.147420 -0.121906 -1.994394 -0.787269
      2      0.433026 -0.267317 -0.025905  0.319356  1.107708  0.292941
      3      1.203037 -0.549309  0.289094  0.460903  0.244544 -0.470807
3     0     -0.965066  0.132708 -0.539879 -0.215790 -0.061912  2.404326
      1      1.028274 -0.476142  0.708160  0.989072 -0.753893 -0.739357
      2      0.228630  1.308473  0.842225  0.314754  0.711959 -0.312829
      3      0.445138  0.195013  0.203581  2.467651  0.918269 -0.348882
4     0     -1.136602  0.400210  2.394704 -1.508321 -0.482093 -0.439026
      1      0.135137 -0.337632  0.917459  0.620601  0.089588  0.141104
      2      1.484537  1.256472 -0.112272 -1.045133  0.826999  0.273049
      3     -1.079805 -0.731970 -0.362180 -0.798009 -1.954512 -1.618571
```

It is same as in `DataFrame` with non unique columns:

```
samples = np.random.randn(6, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(samples, columns=list('11122'))
print (df)
          1         1         1         2         2
0  0.346338 -0.855797 -0.932463 -2.289259  0.634696
1  0.272794 -0.924357 -1.898270 -0.743083 -1.587480
2 -0.519975 -0.136836  0.530178 -0.730629  2.520821
3  0.137530 -1.232763  0.508548 -0.480384 -1.213064
4 -0.157787 -1.600004 -1.287620  0.384642 -0.568072
5 -0.649427 -0.659585 -0.813359 -1.487412 -0.044206

print (df['1'])
          1         1         1
0  0.346338 -0.855797 -0.932463
1  0.272794 -0.924357 -1.898270
2 -0.519975 -0.136836  0.530178
3  0.137530 -1.232763  0.508548
4 -0.157787 -1.600004 -1.287620
5 -0.649427 -0.659585 -0.813359
```

EDIT:

Also for creating `df` from list need unique `labels` (no unique raise error) and function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys`, for `Panel` call [`to_panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_panel.html):

```
np.random.seed(100)
raw_sample = []
labels = list('abcdef')
samples = np.random.randn(6, 5, 4)
for contents in range(samples.shape[0]):
    raw_sample.append(pd.DataFrame(samples[contents]))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(raw_sample, keys=labels)
print (df)
            0         1         2         3
a 0 -1.749765  0.342680  1.153036 -0.252436
  1  0.981321  0.514219  0.221180 -1.070043
  2 -0.189496  0.255001 -0.458027  0.435163
  3 -0.583595  0.816847  0.672721 -0.104411
  4 -0.531280  1.029733 -0.438136 -1.118318
b 0  1.618982  1.541605 -0.251879 -0.842436
  1  0.184519  0.937082  0.731000  1.361556
  2 -0.326238  0.055676  0.222400 -1.443217
  3 -0.756352  0.816454  0.750445 -0.455947
  4  1.189622 -1.690617 -1.356399 -1.232435
c 0 -0.544439 -0.668172  0.007315 -0.612939
  1  1.299748 -1.733096 -0.983310  0.357508
  2 -1.613579  1.470714 -1.188018 -0.549746
  3 -0.940046 -0.827932  0.108863  0.507810
  4 -0.862227  1.249470 -0.079611 -0.889731
d 0 -0.881798  0.018639  0.237845  0.013549
  1 -1.635529 -1.044210  0.613039  0.736205
  2  1.026921 -1.432191 -1.841188  0.366093
  3 -0.331777 -0.689218  2.034608 -0.550714
  4  0.750453 -1.306992  0.580573 -1.104523
e 0  0.690121  0.686890 -1.566688  0.904974
  1  0.778822  0.428233  0.108872  0.028284
  2 -0.578826 -1.199451 -1.705952  0.369164
  3  1.876573 -0.376903  1.831936  0.003017
  4 -0.076023  0.003958 -0.185014 -2.487152
f 0 -1.704651 -1.136261 -2.973315  0.033317
  1 -0.248889 -0.450176  0.132428  0.022214
  2  0.317368 -0.752414 -1.296392  0.095139
  3 -0.423715 -1.185984 -0.365462 -1.271023
  4  1.586171  0.693391 -1.958081 -0.134801
```

---

```
p1 = df.to_panel()
print (p1)
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 6 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 3
Major_axis axis: a to f
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 4
```

EDIT1:

If need MultiIndex `DataFrame` is possible create helper range for unique values, use `concat` and last remove helper level of `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
raw_sample = []
labels = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([labels, range(len(labels))])

samples = np.random.randn(6, 5, 4)
for contents in range(samples.shape[0]):
    raw_sample.append(pd.DataFrame(samples[contents]))

df = pd.concat(raw_sample, keys=mux)
```

---

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
            0         1         2         3
1 0 -1.749765  0.342680  1.153036 -0.252436
  1  0.981321  0.514219  0.221180 -1.070043
  2 -0.189496  0.255001 -0.458027  0.435163
  3 -0.583595  0.816847  0.672721 -0.104411
  4 -0.531280  1.029733 -0.438136 -1.118318
  0  1.618982  1.541605 -0.251879 -0.842436
  1  0.184519  0.937082  0.731000  1.361556
  2 -0.326238  0.055676  0.222400 -1.443217
  3 -0.756352  0.816454  0.750445 -0.455947
  4  1.189622 -1.690617 -1.356399 -1.232435
  0 -0.544439 -0.668172  0.007315 -0.612939
  1  1.299748 -1.733096 -0.983310  0.357508
  2 -1.613579  1.470714 -1.188018 -0.549746
  3 -0.940046 -0.827932  0.108863  0.507810
  4 -0.862227  1.249470 -0.079611 -0.889731
2 0 -0.881798  0.018639  0.237845  0.013549
  1 -1.635529 -1.044210  0.613039  0.736205
  2  1.026921 -1.432191 -1.841188  0.366093
  3 -0.331777 -0.689218  2.034608 -0.550714
  4  0.750453 -1.306992  0.580573 -1.104523
  0  0.690121  0.686890 -1.566688  0.904974
  1  0.778822  0.428233  0.108872  0.028284
  2 -0.578826 -1.199451 -1.705952  0.369164
  3  1.876573 -0.376903  1.831936  0.003017
  4 -0.076023  0.003958 -0.185014 -2.487152
  0 -1.704651 -1.136261 -2.973315  0.033317
  1 -0.248889 -0.450176  0.132428  0.022214
  2  0.317368 -0.752414 -1.296392  0.095139
  3 -0.423715 -1.185984 -0.365462 -1.271023
  4  1.586171  0.693391 -1.958081 -0.134801
```

But create panel is not possible:

```
p1 = df.to_panel()
print (p1)

>ValueError: Can't convert non-uniquely indexed DataFrame to Panel
```

Comment: Please check edit for creating `DataFrame` from list.

Comment: The problem is that, labels cannot be unique, each label is mapped to a sample. They are like samples for machine learning.

Comment: :( duplicates in pandas are suported, but sume function does not work like `reindex`, `concat`.